# how to save byte-array with Dapper and sqlite insert statement

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, insert, arrays, dapper

I have the following code:

```
Shared Sub ExecSQL(ByVal connection As SQLiteConnection, ByVal commandText As String, Optional ByVal param As Object = Nothing)
    If connection Is Nothing Then
        Throw New NullReferenceException("Connection required!")
    End If

    If connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
        connection.Open()
    End If

    connection.Execute(commandText, param)
End Sub

Shared Sub SaveFingerPrints(p As Person)
    For Each f In p.Fingerprints
        ExecSQL($"insert into Prints(id,finger,image,template) values({p.Id},{f.Finger},{f.AsImageData},{f.Template});")
    Next
End Sub
```

I end up with the following insert statement:

```
insert into Prints(id,finger,image,template) values(1,RightThumb,System.Byte[],System.Byte[]);
```

Please how can I fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

```
Shared Sub SavePrints(p As Person)
    For Each f In p.Fingerprints
        cn.Execute("insert into Prints(id,finger,image,template) values(@id,@Finger,@image,@template)",
                   New With {
                   .id = p.Id,
                   .finger = CInt(f.Finger),
                   .image = f.AsImageData,
                   .template = f.Template})
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: For context, we wanted to support the interpreted string syntax and auto-parameterize, but unfortunately in overload resolution, if we do that: string takes precedence over interpreted - so we never get enough context. In hindsight, it is probably for the best: this way, we don't need to do any extra string work etc

Comment: @MarcGravell Is there a simpler way than what i have written above?

Comment: the above is the *intended* usage; you might be able to just pass `f` in as the parameters object, as long as you use `@Id`, `@Template` and `@Image` (depending on case-sensitivity, and what `AsImageData` vs `.image` does) - but what you have looks fine